# Gradle, embedded-kafka: Symbol 'type org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, gradle, apache-kafka, embedded-kafka

I am trying to add [embedded-kafka](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka) to my gradle dependencies.

1. The build passes, but running a test which uses `with EmbeddedKafka` gives the following error:

```
Symbol 'type org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'method io.github.embeddedkafka.ops.ZooKeeperOps.startZooKeeper'.
Make sure that type ServerCnxnFactory is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'ZooKeeperOps.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.zookeeper.server.
```

2. Also, any inputs on what's wrong with the following command?
   `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration testImplementation --dependency embedded-kafka`
   It gives this error:
   `configuration 'testImplementation' not found in configuration container.`
   But printing the "configurations" makes it look like testImplementation is present in configs (printing all configurations prints out `testImplementation` (using `configurations.each { println it.name }`))

Here's a super simplified version of my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.company.scala-common-conventions'
    ...
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation "io.github.embeddedkafka:embedded-kafka_${scalaVersion}:${embeddedKafkaVersion}" //_2.13:3.5.0
}
```

Folder structure:

```
big-mono-repo/
|
|_team/
  |_component/
    |_src/
      |_main/
      |_test/
        |_scala/
        |  |_com.company.foo.bar
        |    |_KafkaEventPublisherSpec // uses `withEmebeddedKafka`
        |_settings.gradle // copied from the big-mono-repo level for now
      |_build.gradle. //the one where I declare embedded-kafka dependency


...
|_build.gradle
|_settings.gradle
```

Questions:

- Any inputs on how to debug this and get the test to run?
- How to check what is causing the gradle failure/ dependency conflict
- Any alternatives to embedded-kafka for simple tests? (I want to test a Producer and some custom Serializer/Deserializers)

Comment: Simple tests? Kafka comes with MockProducer and MockConsumer. You dont need a broker for that

Comment: Sounds like a classpath issue, do you have any exclusion? What does your build definition look like?